# How to plot a SVM model in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, svm

I have a data frame with two classes(0 and 1). Using the dataframe I tried to build and train a SVM model. I used the following code

```
class1.trainset<-data[-class1.testindex,]
class1.trainset <- data.matrix(class1.trainset)
class1.svm.model <- svm(Class ~ ., data = class1.trainset,cost=1:100, cross=10,type="C-classification",kernel="radial",na.action=na.omit)
print(class1.svm.model)
plot(class1.svm.model, class1.trainset)
```

But I am unable to plot the SVM model,it shows an error

```
Error in plot.svm(class1.svm.model, class1.trainset) : missing formula.
```

I tried searching for solution and got this one

[Error in plot, formula missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25716998/error-in-plot-formula-missing)

this showed: I need to define X and Y. But I have 15000 columns in the dataset, how do I define my X and Y using the mentioned code.

```
cplus<-cats
cplus$Oth<-rnorm(nrow(cplus))
m2 <- svm(Sex~., data = cplus)
plot(m2, cplus) #error
plot(m2, cplus, Bwt~Hwt) #Ok
plot(m2, cplus, Hwt~Oth) #Ok
```

And here cplus has only 4 columns, I have 15000 columns

Please help me solve the issue

Comment: have you tried using the `plot.svm()` function from the `e1071` package?

Comment: Yes i tried. It showed couldnt find function "plot.svm"