# SVM Plot does not show any result in R

Tags: r, plot, modeling

I've used the following code :

```
library(e1071)

svm.model<-svm(default.payment.next.month~PAY_AMT6,data=creditdata,cost=5,gamma=1)

plot(svm.model,data=creditdata,fill=TRUE)
```

Comment: Please provide reproducible data. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: can you post screenshot of your error or problem? And specification of what you want achieve.

Comment: @MKR, Nihal : you can also use `library(caret);data("GermanCredit");library(e1071);svm.model <- svm(Amount ~ Duration, data = GermanCredit, cost = 5, gamma = 1);plot(svm.model, data = GermanCredit, fill = TRUE)` for a reproducible example with same issue.

Comment: the dataset is huge.

Comment: Nihal thanks for the response I tried this code .but still it doesnt work.can you please help on this

Comment: i use the german credit card data from kaggle

Comment: @Ruser, i posted code _for reproducible example_ as your `data=creditdata` was not not shared in question and your issue can be reproduced using the posted code

Comment: Thanks.I used the same code which you have given.It does not plot anything and it doesnt throw any error also

Comment: @parth can you please help on this

Comment: @Ruser, the explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25717154/6779509) might help you along with Prem's answer. Also, can you share the class of `default.payment.next.month`,`PAY_AMT6` columns in your data ?

Answer (score 1):

Using a reproducible example provided by @parth you can try something like below.

```
library(caret)
library(e1071)

#sample data
data("GermanCredit")

#SVM model
svm.model <- svm(Class ~ Duration + Amount + Age, data = GermanCredit)

#plot SVM model
plot(svm.model, data = GermanCredit, Duration ~ Amount)
```

Here I ran a classification model so `y` (i.e. `Class` in above case) in `?svm` should be a `factor` (you can verify this using `str(GermanCredit)`).

Once the model is built you can plot it using `plot`. `?plot.svm` says that you need to provide `formula` (by fixing 2 dimensions i.e. `Duration ~ Amount` in above case) if more than two independent variables are used in your model. You may also be interested in `slice` option (for more detail refer `?plot.svm`).